# "В газетах, видели, что пишут?" Вопрос: что выделено запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, спп, вводные-слова, обращение

Предложение интересное с точки зрения структуры. Здесь можно по-разному определить структуру и в зависимости от этого поставить по-разному знаки. Как вам кажется? Какая трактовка более убедительная? Поправьте, пожалуйста, где неправильно дано объяснение и названа структура предложения, так как делаю только догадки. Заодно узнаю, есть ли такие "вещи" в русском языке. А может, у вас будут свои какие-то варианты или уточнения?

- **В газетах, видели, что пишут?** Здесь три варианта трактовки. 1. **видели** — вводное слово (вроде, *знаете ли*). 2. **видели** — обращение или что-то вроде обращения (ср. В газетах видели, что пишут — констатация факта). 3. **видели** — главная часть СПП. Но здесь возникает вопрос: как главная часть может быть внутри придаточной? (В газетах, [видели], что пишут)? Однако, если части поменять: [Видели], (что пишут в газетах)? — всё выглядит логично.
- **В газетах, видели, что пишут?** Трактовка запятой такая: она ставится между стоящими рядом членами предложения, чтобы показать, что между ними нет зависимости, что обстоятельство относится к другому сказуемому (ср. В газетах видели, что пишут? *видели (где?) в газетах* и В газетах, видели, что пишут? *пишут (где?) в газетах*)
- **В газетах видели, что пишут?** При отсутствии запятой перед **видели** нужно тогда и знак вопроса убрать: **В газетах видели, что пишут.**
- На всякий случай вопрос. Могут ли эти трактовки не исключать одна другую? Т.е. одновременно и обращение, и его роль в качестве главной части СПП.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Смысл везде один: **Видели, что пишут в газетах?** Это **вопрос.**

Возможен вариант с инверсией и тем же смыслом: **В газетах, видели, что пишут?**

"Видели" —  это не вводное, а опорное  слово в СПП с придаточным изъяснительным.

2) Сравнить:  В газетах, **видели,** что пишут: этот проект скоро  закрывается. Я, **знаете,** теперь привык, а  сначала трудно было.

Здесь "видели", "знаете" —  вводные слов со значением привлечения внимание собеседника (что-то вроде риторического вопроса). Предложения **утвердительные**.

Comment: *"В газетах, видели, что пишут?"* Получается, что главное предложение разрывает придаточное на две части и поэтому главное обособляется? Такое описано  в теории?

Comment: Здесь, наверное, не надо ставить запятую: В газетах вИдели, что пишут? Тогда обстоятельство переходит из придаточной части в главную. Но это вопросительное предложение. В утвердительном варианте  мы уже имеем вводное слово, которое можно убрать из предложения: В газетах (вот) что пишут...

Comment: Я тоже думал, что вторая запятая не нужна. Но... появляется иной смысл (Видели ли люди, работающие в газетах, что пишут?). В общем, я запутался.